# Which test could I write to force the following code

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, tdd, coffeescript

I like to have my test to force my design but when I comes to collections I always run into problems. The code I want to force is the following:

```
clientInvoices : (client, callback)->

  @all (invoices)->

    callback invoice \
    for invoice in invoices \
    when invoice.data.clientId() is client.data._id()
```

At first I wrote:

```
it 'should get randomid1 invoices', ->

  subject.clientInvoices client, (invoices)->

    invoices.length.should_be 3
```

But since you need to make the test pass with the least amount of effort you could make this pass by doing

```
clientInvoices : (client, callback)->

  @all (invoices)-> callback [1,2,3]
```

The code is in Coffee-Script but examples in Python, Ruby or JavaScript are all appreciated.

Comment: Is it a crappy question? Could adjust it if things aren't clear.

Comment: What is the question?  How to test the first function?

Comment: The question is: which test do I write that forces me to write the first function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
for invoice in invoices \
when invoices.data.clientId() is client.data._id()
```

I think you must mean

```
for invoice in invoices \
when invoice.data.clientId() is client.data._id()
```

If that's the case, then the solution to your quandary is simply to add more assertions about the `invoices` object received by the callback, e.g.

```
invoice.data.clientId().should_be client.data._id() for invoice in invoices
```

(or whatever is the correct syntax for assertions in your test—you used `should_be` in your example). With that extra assertion, it's easier for you to make your function work properly than to have it generate fake data.

Comment: The invoiceS was indeed a typo. Adding extra tests is what I am doing at the moment. Guess I'll just continue to do that. Thanks for the answer.